# Generate Image Control in C# with ManipulationDelta event

Tags: c#, image, xaml, windows-runtime

I'm having a problem dealing with events. Basically the program generate images but with the same event.

```
 private Image MakeImage(string filename)
 {
     Uri uri = new Uri("ms-appx:///CategoryData/" + filename+".png");
     BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage(uri);
     Image image = new Image()
     {
         Height = 100,
         Width = 100,
         Stretch = Stretch.Uniform,
         MaxHeight = 250,
         MaxWidth  = 250,
         HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
         VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
         Name = filename+"Img",
         ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.TranslateX | ManipulationModes.TranslateY,
     };
     image.Source = bitmap;
     image.ManipulationDelta += image_ManipulationDelta;
     return image;
 }

 void image_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     Image image = sender as Image;
     CompositeTransform ct = image.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform;
     ct.TranslateX += e.Delta.Translation.X;
     ct.TranslateY += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
     //throw new NotImplementedException();
 }
```

and exception occurs on the "`ct.TranslateX += e.Delta.Translation.X;`".
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your cast to `CompositeTransform`, because probably it's the wrong type -- Resulting in `ct` being `null`, thus into your exception.

EDIT: added an example.

```
CompositeTransform ct = image.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform;
if (ct == null) image.RenderTransform = ct = new CompositeTransform();
ct.TranslateX += e.Delta.Translation.X;
ct.TranslateY += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
```

Besides, why not using a `TranslateTransform` if all you need is translating the image?

Comment: @NeilGardose I don't see you setting the image's `RenderTransform` to a `CompositeTransform` anywhere. You should do it at least once, before operating on it. Try to use the code I edited in my post.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Eve :) It worked pretty well.

I use CompositeTransform to add scale and rotation on my project.